# Dynamic Programming (Event Organising)

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

Task is to calculate maximum cost that is possible for time-period of 48 hours by choosing orders inputed.Orders are selected in such a way that they do not overlap.

for example if the input is as follows

4

1 2 100

2 3 200

3 4 1600

1 3 2100

Then the output will be 3700 by choosing last 2 events .

Note in case of overlapping events only the event that would yield in maximum cost should be choosen.

Input

The first line of the input contains an integer T, the number of test cases. T test cases follow. The first line of  test case contains an integer N, the number of received orders for conducting events. Each of the next N lines contains three space separated integers Si, Ei, Ci, the parameters of the i-th event described in the problem statement.
Constraints

1 ≤ T ≤ 10

1 ≤ N ≤ 2000

0 ≤ Si < Ei ≤ 48

0 ≤ Ci ≤ 10^6

Output

Output for each test case should contain a single integer in a separate line, the max cost possible.

This is a standard DP problem Here is my code.I have tested for all the possible test cases I could think of but when I submit this code to the online judge I get Wrong answer as the result.Please help.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
unsigned long long A[50][50];
int main()
{
int t,m,S,E,C,i,j;
unsigned long long cost;

 scanf("%d",&t);
while(t--)
{

    int n=-1;


    scanf("%d",&m);

    for(i=0;i<50;++i)
    for(j=i;j<50;++j)
    A[i][j]=0;

    while(m--)
    {

        scanf("%d%d%d",&S,&E,&C);
        A[S][E]=C;
        if(E>n)
        n=E;
    }

    for(int l=2;l<=(n+1);++l)
    {
        for(i=0;i<=(n-l+1);++i)
        {
            j=i+l-1;

            for(int k=i;k<=j;++k)
            {
                cost=A[i][k]+A[k][j];
                if(cost>A[i][j])
                {
                    A[i][j]=cost;

                }
            }
        }
    }
   cout<<A[0][n]<<endl;


}

}
```

Comment: Link to original question : http://www.codechef.com/OCT12/problems/MAXCOMP

Comment: Change cout to printf re-tag as C question. C folks are much better in analysing such obfuscated code. My advice: test first and last possible hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not taken into consideration the following:
**Note in case of overlapping events only the event that would yield in maximum cost should be choosen**

The logic you have used is correct.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
unsigned long long A[50][50];
int main()
{
int t,m,S,E,C,i,j;
unsigned long long cost;

 scanf("%d",&t);
while(t--)
{

    int n=-1;


    scanf("%d",&m);

    /*for(i=0;i<50;++i)
    for(j=i;j<50;++j)
    A[i][j]=0;
    */
    memset(A,0,sizeof(A));

    while(m--)
    {

        scanf("%d%d%d",&S,&E,&C);
        A[S][E]= (C>A[S][E])?C:A[S][E];
        if(E>n)
        n=E;
    }

    for(int l=2;l<=(n+1);++l)
    {
        for(i=0;i<=(n-l+1);++i)
        {
            j=i+l-1;

            for(int k=i;k<=j;++k)
            {
                cost=A[i][k]+A[k][j];
                if(cost>A[i][j])
                {
                    A[i][j]=cost;

                }
            }
        }
    }
   cout<<A[0][n]<<endl;


}

}
```